# Making a card game, need a JTextField to update everytime a card is added to the players deck

Tags: java, swing, listener

I am making a card game (specifically a deck building game for those that know what that is!) and throughout the game, a player will "buy" cards to add to their deck, and each card has a point value associated with it. I have a JTextField that I want to update every time a card is added to the player deck and I'm not really sure how to go about it. I tried adding this:

```
    int deckScore = 0;
    for (Card d : player_1_deck)
    {
        deckScore += d.getValue();
    }
    deckScoreTextBox.setText(Integer.toString(deckScore));
```

but I wasn't really sure it would work (hint: it didn't). It did, however, work if I put it under the mouseClickEvent of each of the card slots. The problem with this is that other players will be able to add cards to your deck and take cards away, which wouldn't update immediately. My google-foo has lead me to think I need to use a listener of some sort, but I'm still kind of a noob and not really sure how that works, and am having trouble understanding the tutorials and guides. If I'm correct and a listener is in fact necessary, how would something like that work? If not, what other options do I have?

I'm not sure what SSCCE would be needed as this is a broader question than just my app, but you can see from my snippet above, my textbox is named deckScoreTextBox and I'm using deckScore as my variable.

Comment: It depends on what kind of listener you need. Typically they're implemented as private inner classes to the object that needs to do the listening, for example the ActionListener

Comment: It sounds like you need to provide some kind of notification when the deck is changed, yes?

Comment: @MadProgrammer That sounds like a good idea, but I don't see any methods of the ArrayList class that I can use to notify the app for a change. How would that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is where *[encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29)* goes in.

Suppose you have your deck in an array list:

```
ArrayList<Card> deck = new ArrayList<>();
```

Now when you add or remove cards to/from your deck, you propabbly just call `add` and `remove` functions of the list.

There is a better idea: create two functions `addCard` and `removeCard`, these will be the only way to manipulate with cards in deck (and `shuffle`, etc), and resolve recomputing of deck value only in functions that affect count of cards.

You could also want create a separate class `Deck` and make field `deck` private, so you can 100% guarantee that everyone (= you if you program alone) uses only the safe functions `addCard`, ... and doesnt call list's functions directly.

How it could look like:

```
class Deck {
  private ArrayList<Card> deck = new ArrayList<>();
  //only this class can see and work with this field

  ...
  //everyone can see and call this method
  public void addCard(Card newCard) {
    deck.add(newCard);
    gui.updateDeckValue(); //or something like that
  }
}
```

Comment: I like this idea. Would I just add my little snippet above to the end of the addCard and removeCard methods?

Comment: @lfernandes No...You would create a observable interface that would be used to register interest to the deck, so that when changes occurred, you would run through this list of registered "listeners" and notify them of the changes to the state of the deck. You would place you snippet within one of these registered "listeners"

Comment: I was going to upvote, but you tightly coupled the model to the view...this is not the best choice of design...

Comment: Thank you both very much. I'll do some more googling now that I have some things to go by and see what I can pull off.

Comment: @kajacx - just wanted to pop in and let you know that the addCard and removeCard methods worked brilliantly, thanks!